# How can I provide the password in Linux Script

Tags: linux

I need to write a shell script for connecting to different Linux machines and deleting files there.

For example,

```
ssh booksserver 
rm -rf Books-ws.war
```

Now, my question is, how can  I provide the password (required when executing  ssh booksserver )?

Comment: PRobably already obvious but, I suppose you know you can write the command in the same line to execute that rm -rf in bookserver right?

Answer (score 1):

You should create key pair and use it instead of passwords. Google for a instructions how to do it, e.g. http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't provide the password. You should set up [public key authentication](http://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/) run `ssh-agent` to login without the system requesting you for a password.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have a passphrase-less private key on the client side, paired with a public key in the server-side authorized_keys file with a specific command (such as `rm -rf Books-ws.war`, or some shell-script that does the same) that gets run.

For example, having the following in `.ssh/authorized_keys2` for the given user on the remote host:

```
command="date" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIw[...]Q== Comment for passphraseless key
```

Will *only* ever run `date` when you connect using that key:

```
[localhost] % ssh -i /path/to/id user@remotehost         
Sun 20 Nov 2011 20:29:59 EST
Connection to remotehost closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but must use key-based authentication instead.

That is:

- You create a public and private key (without passphrase)
- The public key is copied to the booksserver
- You pass the username and key to ssh as this: ssh user@booksserver -i keyfile

There are a lot of tutorials for this, and the concrete steps may vary from distribution to distribution. For Ubuntu, this one is a good one: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: You could do it with a pass phrase too but then would have run an agent and add it once before running your script.